# Xamarin Forms Access every child element's Property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

First of all, I am a beginner.

**I want to access every child element of different types inside a Stack Layout.**

I tried but could not find any solution.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.9.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NewExp.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainPage">

  <StackLayout x:Name="first">
    <StackLayout x:Name="second">
      <Label Text="label1"/>
      <Label Text="label2"/>
      <Label Text="label3"/>
      <Label Text="label4"/>
      <Label Text="label5"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="third">
      <Button Text="BTN" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NewExp
{
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Type type;
      Label label;
      // I want to access each child and change there's property eg. Text

      var _list = second.Children.ToList();

      for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
      {
        // Not working
        //_list[i].Text = "New Text";


        // Not working
        //type = _list[i].GetType();
        //var _lst = (type)_list[i];
        //_lst.Text = "New Text";


        // Working, but I need to know previously that it is a Label
        // and this is not real world case.
        // I also used Linq, but no benefit

        label = (Label)_list[i];
        label.Text = "New Text";        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion will be most appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: directly modifying the UI this way is generally a really bad idea.  Using data binding would be a much better approach.

Comment: Why don't you assign a name like <Label x:Name="firstLabel"> etc. so you can access them like that?

Comment: @Jason Would you please describe.

Comment: @stersym Every x:Name actually a private variable. so it will consume memory; I showed a sample page here, if this page growing large then assigning every element a name will cause problem.

Comment: Maybe a collection view or something similar would help you.

Comment: DataBinding is well covered in the docs.  Or @stersym suggests, a ListView/CollectionView or BindableLayout might be a good choice.  You haven't really described what you're trying to do so it's hard to know what to suggest.  And your concern about memory usage seems wildly misplaced - you are already instantiating the UI objects - simply creating another reference to them will not have any significant impact on memory.

Comment: @Jason I want to access each child and change there's property eg. Text.  `Container[index].Text = "New Text"` I already showed it with example in MainPage.xaml.cs. Please see the full code and code comment.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but not the underlying use case.  Is this data build dynamically?  Are there a varying number of rows?  If so, then a ListView/CollectionView/BindableLayout would make sense.

Comment: @Jason No, there are no rows. Simply access and change child element property based on certain condition dynamically. I can actually access child element but not its property, without knowing what is the element type and `GetType or typeof` does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I noted in the comments, directly modifying the UI this way is generally a bad idea and would be better achieved with data binding.  However, if you hae to do it, something like this should work

```
foreach (var c in second.Children)
{
  if (c is Label l)
  {
    l.Text = "some new text";
  }

  // repeat for any other types
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here I need to do lot of if-elseif every time when I want to change something.  If there any simple approach, then it will be beneficial.

Comment: again, you are being incredibly vague about this.  What is "something"?  Is it a property that all UI elements have?  Or only some?  If they all have a common property then you should be able to test for the base type that implements that property.

Comment: May be I could not express what I want. I checked your approach as accepted answer. Thanks.